# How to check if data in linked list exists C++

Tags: c++, list

I'm working on creating a function that will remove an item from a linked list, however, I'm unsure how to check if the item passed to the function exists in the linked list. Because of this, my program crashes in the event that it gets an input it doesn't recognize.

Here is my function:

```
bool StringList::remove(string rmData){
    StringNode *current = new StringNode;
    StringNode *previous = new StringNode;
    current = head;
    while(current->data != rmData){
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    previous->next = current->next;
}
```

How can I check if the data exists in the list?

Comment: You're not checking in your loop to see if you've reached the end of the list.  And you're leaking memory with your `new` calls.  You don't need them here.

Answer (score 0):

You always need to check if `current->next` points to a null, if so `break;`